# Does MyRange.Cells(i,j) truly return an Excel.Range?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

First things first, I emphasis I am under a VSTO / .Net environment, using Visual Studio 2017. No VBA here.

You have a `MyRange as Excel.Range = something` object and you want to refer to the top left cell of that range. Two options:

- `MyRange.Range("A1")`
- `MyRange.Cells(1,1)`

But then, although the documentation indicates `.Cells()` returns an `Excel.Range` object, Intellisense will not pick it up as such. For example, `MyRange.Cells(1,1).Value2` is not readily available from the  Intellisense drop down list. However, if you do manually type in `.Value2`, it will work no problem.

My question is: Is this some limitation from Visual Studio, or does this have some implication at compilation and subsequently at runtime?

First I started to use `.Range("A1")`, but that becomes quite unconvenient when dealing with dynamic references, such as an equivalent to `.Cells(i,j)`.
So instead, I created my own Extension, which relies on implicit conversion. Is that ok? (second question)

```
Module RangeExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a Range object that represents the cell in the specified range.
    ''' </summary>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function Cell(ByVal MyRange As Excel.Range, ByVal RowIndex As Long, ByVal ColumnIndex As Long) As Excel.Range
        Return MyRange.Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a Range object that represents the cell in the specified worksheet.
    ''' </summary>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function Cell(ByVal MySheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal RowIndex As Long, ByVal ColumnIndex As Long) As Excel.Range
        Return MySheet.Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no limitation of Visual Studio, but rather one of the properties on the `System.Object` type.

`rangeReference.Cells` is a property on the `Range` type that returns an `Excel.Range` object.

`rangeReference.Cells(1,1)` is a shortcut way of writing `rangeReference.Cells.Item(1,1)`. `Item` is the default property on the `Range` object.  Unfortunately, `Item` is defined as a `Variant` type within Excel and .Net represents the `Variant` type using the `System.Object` type.  For Intellisense to recognize `Item` as a `Range`, it needs to be cast to a `Range` type.

**Example:**

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range = Sheet1.Range("A1:B4")
Dim rngCells As Excel.Range = rng.Cells
Dim specificCell As Object
specificCell = rngCells(1, 1)
' or
specificCell = rngCells.Item(1, 1)
Dim specificCellRange As Excel.Range = CType(specificCell, Excel.Range)
```

---

> However, if you do manually type in .Value2, it will work no problem.

This implies that you are working with `Option Strict Off` which allows late-binding; the property is discovered at run-time. Late-binding does impose a performance hit in that `Value2` must be *discovered* and and then retrieved.  This is done via extra code that the compiler inserts to support the property retrieval.

Comment: I see.. And your comment on .Value2 is very interesting! Regarding the cast, would I gain anything if I included a CType statement in my extensions? At the moment the cast is implicit..

Comment: @Ama, in extension methods case, the implicit casting is fine.  In general though, you will be better off by enabling Option Strict.  Yes, it is a bit more keyboard work, but in the end you will save time trying to tack down subtle errors that can creep in when relying on the compiler to make your code compile and run.

Comment: Totally agreed! Thanks again.